# ajax call to webservice always results in error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm making the following call to a webservice:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType:'json',
    cache:false,
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");            
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('Failed to subscribe.');
    }  
});
```

The webservice is hit and definitely returns json - I can hit it via the browser and get what I expect. In my site, the error function is always called.

using Fiddler I can see there is a 200 result - the only thing I notice is that in the response fiddler says

> Response is encoded and may require decoding before inspection. Click here to transform.

When I click it, the response goes from being a load of random symbols to being my expected json.

Upon Googling this, I see suggestions of adding `contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",` to my call.

This stops my webservice function from being hit at all.

I tried changing it to POST also, just to see if that was the issue...still doesn't work.

Can anyone point out what I', doing wrong?

EDIT:
I've just noticed I'm getting this in Chrome

> Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:57631/Api/Products/SubscribeEmailMeWhenAvailable/203/wrfw@wrwq.com?_=1447757623275. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50217' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: where is js fiddle link?

Comment: remove dataType and try, let jquery decide.

Comment: In error function do console.log(thrownError) and check what error is it giving

Comment: thrownError is an empty string ""

Comment: @Sandeeproop - just going to try that - this project is a dog tho, and takes 5 minutes to build...

Comment: what is the response status ?? Try console.log(ajaxOptions).

Comment: It can be related to CORS policy.

Comment: ajaxOptions just says "error"

Comment: Removing dataType doesn't work.

Comment: @user2181397 I can't provide a jsfiddle as the webservice is a local one on my machine.

Comment: Once again. Browser restricts CORS.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - I Googled it - HTTP access control (CORS) - So how do I work around it?

Comment: You configure the server the request is being made to so it sends the CORS headers which grant the browser permission to give the content to the JS.

Answer (score 0):

This message seems related to gzip compression.

Have you tried this ?

```
headers: { "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip,deflate,sdch" }
```

Result :

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip,deflate,sdch" } 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:'json',
    cache:false,
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");            
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('Failed to subscribe.');
    }  
});
```

Comment: Hi, Just tried this but is hasn't made any difference.

Comment: Hi, see my edit (modified headers and added contentType)

Comment: When I change to the above, I get this error `A public action method 'SubscribeEmailMeWhenAvailable' was not found on controller 'Website.Areas.Api.Controllers.ProductsController'.`

Comment: Sorry, no idea about this one 0_o

Comment: thanks for your help anyway.